# How can I ensure that a new Person is created on each loop?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

Please see the code below, which is part of my unit test:

```
mockPersonFactory.Setup(m => m.Create()).Returns(PersonFactory());

public IPerson PersonFactory()
{
    IPerson iPerson = new Person();
    return iPerson;
}
```

`PersonFactory`should be called multiple times (because it is contained in a loop in the code being tested).  However, instead of creating a new `Person`every time in the loop it is reusing the same person object every time.  How can I ensure that a new Person is created on each loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code just says "use the return value of `PersonFactory()` as the return value of `Create()`."  Instead, you need to instruct it to *call* `PersonFactory()` to get the return value each time.  Use the overload of `Returns` that accepts a lambda:

```
mockPersonFactory.Setup(m => m.Create()).Returns(() => PersonFactory());
```

Or simply just:

```
mockPersonFactory.Setup(m => m.Create()).Returns(PersonFactory);
```

Comment: `.Returns(PersonFactory)` would also work I believe.

Comment: Thanks.  Person objects are created by Castle Windsor in the code being tested.  Is it acceptable to do something like this in a unit test or should I be using IOC for Mock Objects as well? Thanks again.  +1 for the answer - it works.

Comment: Just depends on what you're testing.  I wouldn't use an IOC container during unit tests under virtually all circumstances because you should be supplying dependencies yourself (as mocks or stubs).  Feel free to post another question with more specifics.